# In string search for number to determine next in sequence?

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic-arrays, string-search

I have a list of build numbers (e.g. R1079-AAA-001, ...-002 etc.) in which the value of "R1079" changes depending on the machine being used. What I want to do is search through the list to determine the last used build number (the last 3 digits) in relation to the specific machine I intend to use. I then need to add one and create a new log for the new build i.e. the last R1079 build was 056, therefore the new one is 057.

Currently the THEORY I have is an in string search for the machine number followed by a number search and store in the string and converted to integer. This is then added into a dynamic array and the maximum found when the loop is complete. One is added to this integer and the new name placed into a cell.

However, the code I have doesn't work so I assume I am missing things/got it all wrong.

Code below:

```
Sub test()

Dim x As String
Dim n As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim Machine_EBM As String
Dim retval As String
Dim retvalint As Integer
Dim LastBuild As Integer
Dim NextBuild As Integer
Dim myarr() As Integer

Machine = "R1079"

x = Cells("A1").Value 'get the first string in the list
    n = 1
    Do Until x = ""
        If InStr(x, Machine) > 0 Then 'search for machine in string
            For i = 6 To Len(Str) 'search for numbers at end of string
                If Mid(x, i, 1) >= "0" And Mid(x, i, 1) <= "9" Then
                    retval = retval + Mid(s, i, 1) 'store numbers
                End If
            Next i
            retvalint = CInt(retval) ' convert to integer
            ReDim Preserve myarr(n)
            myarr(n) = retvalint ' store integer value in array
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Loop

    LastBuild = Worksheet.Function.Max(myarr(n)) ' determine maximum array value
    NewBuild = LastBuild + 1 'add one to the value

    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell = Machine = "-AAA-" + NewBuild 'input new build number

End Sub
```

I am fairly new to VBA and self taught so I realise there may be a lot of errors here that I am missing. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,

Charlie

Comment: Say, how store your build code in your excel sheet. I means, what range or what column. So, I can give more.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small piece of code for getting new build no for inputted build no.

I already tested the code. It give me right answer. So, you can use this code.

```
Public Sub getBuildNo()

    Dim machineCode, lastBuildCode, newBuildCode As String
    Dim buildNo As Integer

    'Set machine code
    machineCode = "R1079"

    'Set last build code
    lastBuildCode = Range("A1")

    'Get last build no
    buildNo = Right(lastBuildCode, 3)

    'Increase 1
    buildNo = buildNo + 1

    'Get new build No
    newBuildCode = machineCode & "-AAA-"

    'adding prefix 0s for getting like (001, 002, 025, etc.)
    If buildNo < 10 Then
        newBuildCode = newBuildCode & "00" & buildNo
    ElseIf buildNo < 100 Then
        newBuildCode = newBuildCode & "0" & buildNo
    Else
        newBuildCode = newBuildCode & buildNo
    End If

    'show new code
    Range("C1") = newBuildCode

End Sub
```